# JQuery/Javascript: Getting locally changed booleans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some trouble with booleans and scope. I have set a global boolean to false, upon a function the boolean turns true. if the boolean is true I want another function to run. However the boolean is only changed in the scope of the function that makes it true and is still false globally. Thus the following function which needs the boolean to be true is not running.

The first part of my code looks something like this:

```
let threePick= false;
let twoPick = false;
let onePick = false;
let found = false;
var startGame = false;
function selector() {
    $("#threebut").click(function () {
        if (found === false) {
            found = true;
            onePick = true;
            twoPick = true;
            var input = this;
            input.disabled = true;
        }
    })
    $("#onebut").click(function () {
        if (found === false) {
            found = true;
            threePick = true;
            twoPick = true;
            var input = this;
            input.disabled = true;
        }
    })
    $("#twobut").click(function () {
        if (found === false) {
            found = true;
            threePick = true;
            onePick=true;
            var input = this;
            input.disabled = true;
        };
    });
};
selector();
function enemy() {
    $("#twobut").click(function () {
        if (twoPick === true){
        var input = this;
        input.disabled = true;
       startGame = true;
    }
    });
   $("#threebut").click(function() {
       if (threePick === true){

        input.disabled = true;
        startGame = true;   
       }
   });
   $("#twobut").click(function() {
       if (twoPick === true){
        var input = this;
        input.disabled = true;
        startGame = true; 
       }
   });
}
enemy();
```

Notice that the enemy(); changes the startGame boolean to true
Now in the next part of my code:

```
function gameStart(){
    if (startGame === true){
        var button = $('<button/>', {
            text: 'Attack'
        })
        $('#atkButton').append(button);
    }
}
gameStart();
```

I want the function to run when the boolean is true but the boolean only changes locally. I know that accessing local variables is not possible but is there any way around this or an alternative I could use?

P.S I apologise for my inefficient code I've only been doing javascript for a few days.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think it's a local variable? It's declared outside all the functions.

Answer (score 1):

`gameStart()` is called immediately after it is defined and only once. At this time the value of `startGame` is `false`.

`enemy()` sets up eventlisteners for clicks on buttons `#threebut` and `#twobut`. Only when one of these buttons is clicked is the value of `startGame` set to true. If `gameStart()` is called thereafter it will see that `startGame` is true.

Comment: I see, so should I call gameStart() within the if statements of  enemy? Thanks for the help! edit: Yup, I got it to work! Thanks!

Comment: @SasankGanapathiraju If you do that you'll start the game every time the user clicks on one of those buttons. Is that what you want?

Comment: I made it so the other buttons become disabled, it worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your two functions `selector` and `enemy` define event handlers for the click action on elements in your HTML. Unless you click on those elements these event handlers, and attached functions, are not called.

Your `id=twobut` element has three different event handlers attached which will all fire when that element is clicked.

Normally in jQuery you use `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` in which you can call `selector();` and `enemy();` so this run when the DOM is properly loaded and the event handlers can be attached successfully.

Maybe add the HTML from your page to create a working example?